# Timecop with Factory_girl: factory not sequencing date attribute as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot, timecop

I am using the [timecop](https://rubygems.org/gems/timecop) gem in order to stub out dates.  I am also using [factory_girl](https://rubygems.org/gems/factory_girl_rails) in order to make creating objects for my specs easier.

Here is my factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :fiscal_year do
    start_date  {Date.today}
    end_date    {Date.today + 1.day}

    trait(:sequenced_start_date) {sequence(:start_date, Date.today.year)  {|n| Date.new(n, 10, 1) }}
    trait(:sequenced_end_date)   {sequence(:end_date,   Date.today.year + 1)  {|n| Date.new(n, 9, 30) }}


    factory :sequenced_fiscal_year, parent: :fiscal_year,
            traits: [:sequenced_start_date, :sequenced_end_date]
  end
end
```

Assume that today's **actual** date is 09/07/2016.

Here is my spec:

```
RSpec.describe FiscalYear, type: :model do
  before(:example) do
    Timecop.freeze(Time.local(2010))
  end
  after do
    Timecop.return
  end

  describe "fake spec to show unexpected sequence behavior" do
    it "tests something" do
      puts "Today's frozen date thanks to Timecop: #{Date.today}"
      fiscal_year = create(:sequenced_fiscal_year)
      puts "Sequenced Date: #{fiscal_year.end_date}"
    end
  end
end
```

When the spec is run here is the output:

```
Today's frozen date thanks to Timecop: 01/01/2010
Sequenced Date: 09/30/2017
```

In the first output line: Timecop works as expected when I call `Date.today`.  It has successfully frozen the time and returns that frozen time.

However: the second line does not work as expected.  It is clearly using the system `Date` as opposed to Timecop's frozen `Date`.  The sequenced `end_date` should sequentially add +1 year to the currently frozen Date.  Therefore: I expect the `end_date` here to be `09/30/2011`, as opposed to `09/30/2017`.

How can I make it so that the sequenced `end_date` attribute goes off of Timecop's `Date` as opposed to the system's `Date`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with the second argument I was passing into the `sequence` method. That argument is static/evaluated at initialization.  It is not dynamic, so `timecop` did not have the chance to stub out the date before that second argument is evaluated.

```
trait(:sequenced_end_date) {sequence(:end_date, Date.today.year + 1)  {|n| Date.new(n, 9, 30) }}
```

That `Date.today.year` part of the second argument being passed into the `sequence` method is static and evaluated at initialization.  It is not dynamic and is already evaluated before the method is even called.

I simply needed to change those methods to the following:

```
trait(:sequenced_year_start_date) {sequence(:start_date)  {|n| Date.new(Date.today.year, 10, 1) }}
trait(:sequenced_year_end_date)   {sequence(:end_date)    {|n| Date.new(Date.today.year + n, 9, 30) }}
```

Now it works as expected and returns the following:

```
Today's frozen date thanks to Timecop: 01/01/2010
Sequenced Date: 09/30/2011
```

Blocks are dynamic, so calling `Date.today.year + n` within the block gives timecop the chance to first stub out `Date` before this block is executed.

Comment: yep - was just going to say something similar.  It's more that `Date.today.year` is evaluated upon initialization than at runtime which is the issue.

Comment: @Anthony thanks for the correction.  I'll change that to be more precise.